# Most efficient "next-day" function?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, datetime, delta

I want to write a function that takes 'yyyymmdd' as its input and generates the next day (same 'yyyymmdd' format output). This function can be applied to solve problems like next-week or next-t-days.

I know that this task can be easily done using the `time.delta` approach. However, what is inside the `time` library? I mean, what sort of computation did it do to solve this "next-day" problem?

In Python, I wrote my own next-day function using a long `if-elif-..-else` statement on the day-level when `int(dd) >= 28`. It worked, but looks extremely ugly and inefficient... So I start to be curious about what's written inside the `time` library...

In particular, I want to know what is the most efficient way of performing such next-day task, and can we prove its optimality of efficiency?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: What's your application that demands something "more efficient" than adding a timedelta object to a datetime object? Can you show an example? I'm kind of having trouble seeing efficiency/performance as an end in itself here.

Comment: Note that finding the next week or the next month by iterating over days is not efficient in the first place. it is like doing a loop of increments to perform an addition or the same for multiplications/divisions.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Exactly! That's exactly the reason for me to ask for a better way to write something for the .delta task.

Comment: @MrFuppes Sorry for the confusion. I was meant to say this: (1) I wrote an inefficient delta task function, (2) I know that .delta must be better than my own function, and hence (3) how did the library do that? and is there an even more efficient way than delta or no?

Comment: Still, I think your question would benefit from an example. In general, [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) provides [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) arithmetic. You have [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) if time zones play a role. And there's third party libs like dateutil, which provide things like [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html). So, what's stopping you?